# asp.net core webapi with authentication (back-end) and react redux app(front-end) with authentication working independently

Tags: node.js, reactjs, asp.net-core, npm

i need asp.netcore web api with authentication (ApplicationDbContext i.e.identity default database context ). i feel comfortable with visual studio as back-end.

2.i need react-redux app with authentication(front-end) working independently that start with "npm start". i feel good with vs code.  on the front-end i want to add react-redux and redux-thunk to implement my course website front end. i have been in struggle for a week to achieve this.i tried with vs templates but when ever i install react-redux the user management fails and the client app does not start.tried, web application,api and web application with restful templates.

3. if someone have better idea to accomplish my task . my overall problem is to create a website that can present online courses.the teachers could add course material and student can access.

Answer (score 0):

Try running npm install before your create-react-app script.

If that doesn't work, deleting "node_modules" folder and running npm install.

If that doesn't work, you can always try setting up your react environment manually (For example, as in [this great tutorial here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm))

Worst-case, you can always use react just [client-side only](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html), and although this becomes difficult due to most online tutorials being server-side, at least you can get started and not be blocked on your project.

Source: I [googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=Error%3A%20react_app%400.1.0%20start%3A%20%60rimraf%20.%2Fbuild%20%26%26%20react-scripts%20start%60&oq=Error%3A%20react_app%400.1.0%20start%3A%20%60rimraf%20.%2Fbuild%20%26%26%20react-scripts%20start%60&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.331j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ;)

Comment: thanks @Xela Esohg for help i am trying your suggestions.in another project i created react app and asp.net core web api separatly  but you know that asp.net core web api does not have authentication in vs template .that is why i started using reactapp with auth template. the said project got the same error like this

Comment: @FiazAhmed I've found a tutorial here that might be useful? https://www.pointblankdevelopment.com.au/blog/135/react-redux-with-aspnet-core-20-login-registration-tutorial-example 

No idea. It's also possible to implement authentication yourself using jwt and cookies.